# Retrieve data from db using Substring in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, substring

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In a project, I have to search data from db using `SUBSTRING` of a field. Its like, I have a field `value`, which has values like "2.5/8.2","4.1/5.9","3.9/8.3",..... . So, I have to search values like "2.5","4.1","3.9",.... . That means, I have to search for the values `WHERE SUBSTRING(value,1,INSTR("/"))=2.5`. I tried this code in my project, but it doesn't return the values which it should.

I think I should use `Virtual Fields` here. I read the examples also, but I didn't understand how to use it. Can anybody help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Virtual Fields` you can use `SUBSTRING` in your query directly:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'SUBSTRING(Model.value, 1, INSTR("/"))' => 2.5
    )
)) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was also trying this, may be I made a mistake to check the desired result.@Holt

Comment: @user3808903 You can check the `SQL` debug to see what kind of SQL request is outputed for this `find`.